# Rename [screen-record] to [screen-recording]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I suggest renaming the [screen-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-record) tag to "screen-recording".

Firstly, this would make it consistent with the existing [audio-recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording) and [video-recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-recording) tags.

Secondly, there's no such thing as a "screen record", whereas "screen recording" is a well-known activity.  A web search for "screen record" brings up no results that define or even mention a "screen record" - they're all about screen recording.

As the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/screen-record/info) says, it's about screen recording:

> recording of computer screen output